# Responsive h3 element in "footer" div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a "result" division of my page with a header, content, and footer.

The header and content are both working how I expect but I can't seem to get the h3 element in the footer to right-align on the div. If I do; it breaks when I resize the screen. The result_header on the other hand seems to go down gracefully.

A asp-free html markup is the following.

```
   <div id="results">
          <div id="result_header">
            <h3>Tax Estimator Results</h3>
              <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TugDropDown"
                runat="server" CssClass="tugLabel">
              <%=SrcTugList.Count %>  Taxing Unit Groups
              </asp:Label>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="TugDropDown"
                DataTextField="Desc"
                DataValueField="CodeID"
                runat="server" />
            </div>
            <!-- results go here, ignored since it's asp mostly -->
            <div id="result_footer">
            <h3> Total Estimate: </h3> <!-- This is what I want to right align/float on the right border of this div, it is not doing what I expect. -->
            </div>
        </div>


.tugLabel {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
  right: 32%
}

#results select {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2%;
  display: inline;
}

.tugResult{
  position: relative;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 1%;
}

#result_footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #9bc5ee;
}

#result_footer h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 5%;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S7dqx/. Try to fix it and point out where exactly is the problem and then update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly. You want the h3 to go over on the right of the footer div right?
Instead of floating your h3 to the right, how about using text-align: right?